# How to translate THEM

Tags: pronoms

Can anyone please help me translate this sentence.
"These are the children’s books. Well give them to them then"

Many thanks in anticipation
Pete

Comment: Did you mean "**We'll** give them to them then" ? Just wondering if there was a typo.

Comment: Well spotted. You are of course perfectly correct :-)

Comment: I added an additional response based on what you told me - you might consider editing your question so others users are aware :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Ce sont les livres des enfants", puis :

Si on s'adresse à plusieurs personnes ou vouvoiement : "Donnez-les-leur, alors."

Si on s'adresse à une personne et tutoiement : "Donne-les-leur, alors."

Précisions :

- S'il y a plusieurs enfants et un livre : donne-le-leur
- S'il y a plusieurs enfants et plusieurs livres : donne-les-leur
- S'il y a un enfant et un livre : donne-le-lui
- S'il y a un enfant et plusieurs livres : donne-les-lui

Answer (score 2):

The sentence was in fact "**We'll** give them to them then," so your options are as follows:

> « Nous les leur donnerons, alors. »

or

> « On les leur donnera, alors. »

---

**Note** : Because "children" is always the plural of "child" and "books" is always the plural of "book," in my translations I've chosen to not include the same precisions that Georg made in his excellent answer.

Comment: Would it be ok to use the 'futur proche' in this case,and if so, would the "les leur" go **between** the 'allons/va' and the infinitive 'donner,' keeping the same "les/leur"  order?

Comment: I think it could be appropriate, and yes you're right - "les leur" would go between the conjugation of "aller" and the infinitive. In these cases, it would be "On va les leur donner" or "Nous allons les leur donner."